# Android - My app replaces an other one when using the app switcher

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that receives data using intents(ACTION_SEND). When I'm sharing content from Chrome for instance, the content reaches my app, but suddenly my app replaces Chrome in the app switcher. So, if I have my app and Chrome opened, after the data sharing I have two instances of my app(even if the Chrome icon appears in top of that window, if I tap it, opens my app).

Any ideas about what is going on here?

Edit: I can't post code here for legal reasons, but tinkering with it I've discovered that this issue is happening on Android 11 and only sharing links from Chrome(using the share option in the Chrome menu). Sharing links from Firefox works ok.

Comment: I feel like this goes without saying, but can you show us some code?

Comment: Maybe something with the activity back stack or you have to call finish().

Comment: Can you share the method that you share your information with Chrome?